# Ceiling Fan Not Spinning Normally, Replaced Capacitor Already

Tags: ceiling-fan

We've had this house since late June, and the house was renovated. I am not sure if the ceiling fan in question was brand new or simply recently new. It is a Harbor Breeze, Model RLG52NWZ5C3L.

Regardless, we came into our master bedroom one night to see it slowly spinning down to a crawl. Based off of Google searched articles, Reddit posts, and DIY Stackexchange, my first step was to try and replace the capacitor... After waiting a week for the part, it did not fix it.

- Yes, it hums, but I've heard louder humming from older (working) ceiling fans. I am not sure if newer ceiling fans simply are not as loud hummers as they used to be.
- You can kind of see it start to snail-crawl when you first turn it on.
- No, it does not stay spinning if I give it a spin, but
- Yes, it does seemingly freely spin with no obstructions when off.
- Yes, the light works. It has a separate light switch.
- **Update 1:** Voltage from black wire in ceiling measures 118 VAC

I have also tried checking/resecuring all the connected wires that comes downward into the light assembly to ensure they were all actually connected, so I didn't check the wires in the ceiling. I have not voltmeter tested anything. Neither spin direction as expected.

So, at this point, I am at a loss. I don't know if this ceiling fan has a flywheel or not, or how to tell if it does. I don't know what the 2nd black box is, that is around the same size as the capacitor.. but it has 3 wires, one of which being for the light I believe. I am open to suggestions, but I understand if it is not worth fixing anymore past the capacitor.

[image: The "other box"]

**Update 2:** This is the "other box" similar in size to the capacitor. While the manual doesn't mention it, it was stuck to the top of the switch housing area.

**Update 3:** In the pic, I noticed it said E313648, which IS a wattage limiter. From what I understand, that is to regulate the wattage that goes to the light sockets. Can this affect the fan motor too?

**Update 4(Final Update):** The motor is shot.

Comment: Does the fan have a remote wireless receiver switch operated by a remote control?

Comment: None that I see, no.

Comment: Contact whoever renovated it and ask them about the fan. Was it new, etc.?

Comment: I have never heard of these fans having a flywheel. The fan blades would serve the function of a flywheel which function is to load the motor and prevent over speeding. I can imagine that if one was installing a fan and powered it without the blades installed, damage would result.

Comment: I went up to look at the top for a date code, got 0717, assumingly meaning it was built in July 2017. However, I'm pretty sure this was a new install earlier this year by the people that bought the house, renovated it, and sold it to me.
As for flywheel, yeah I did not think a flywheel was common.

Comment: I measured the black wire's voltage from the ceiling and got 118V. I am assuming that's acceptable. I'm not sure where else to check to ensure I'm getting acceptable output voltages. While I was up there, I also messed with those wires to ensure they were all secure.

Comment: Does your ceiling fan have a pull chain to control the speed, or a dimmer switch?

Comment: Pull chain. When I replaced the capacitor, I actually had to attach some of the wires onto the pull chain's box. I made sure to match the uF's, not the color wires. Separate, non-dimmer light switch for the light or fan.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [manual for that fan](http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/080629170322_install.pdf), there is no "extra box" shown, but it does mention that

*"This fan is remote control adaptable (remote control not included). Please refer to instructions provided with the remote control before proceeding with these wiring instructions."*

So my guess is that your extra box is the remote control option, and the previous owner lost the remote, with the fan stuck on "Low". I would remove it and wire it as it should be without a remote.

Another thing to try is the Fwd / Rev switch. it may be old and/or dirty, try flipping it back and forth a few times.

Comment: It had been working fine, changing speeds and everything no problem, up until one night, when it had the symptoms of a bad capacitor (slow spin, hum). I did already try messing with the FWD / REV switch multiple times. 

The most recent ceiling fans that had a remote I installed (4+ years ago?), had the box for it in the canopy, so I didn't think about that box being remote related as it was down below in the switch housing. Looking at this Harbor Breeze remote manual (http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/671961408435_install.pdf) makes me still think I would have seen it in the canopy.

Comment: I wonder if the extra box in the photo is a wattage limiter for the lights?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I noticed in the pic I could see the letter/numbers, E313648, which IS a wattage limiter.