# Ceiling fan randomly slows to a crawl - then speeds back up again

Tags: ceiling-fan

Our ceiling fan is exhibiting an odd behaviour: it starts up nice and fast with a pleasant breeze, but after ~10-20 minutes abruptly slows to a total crawl (around 20 RPM or so). After a minute or two of this, it speeds back up again, then slows down again a minute later, etc. The slow periods get longer and longer until it just stays slow.

The fan is a "Model D5201", no manufacturer on the label (there's an Intertek number on it). It came with a remote control with three fan speeds; using the different fan speeds would cause the fan to spin at an appropriate speed for a bit before slowing down.

I removed the remote control receiver unit, but it still behaves the same way. Right now I have it wired directly to the wall switch without the receiver.

My first thought, as with [Ceiling Fan Not Spinning Normally, Replaced Capacitor Already](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170357/ceiling-fan-not-spinning-normally-replaced-capacitor-already), was to replace the capacitor, so I ordered a brand-new 3.5uF capacitor off Amazon and swapped it in. No dice - still slows down. I've checked the blade balance (seems fine), fan rotation (spins freely and smoothly), and the built-in halogen light works fine.

What might be the problem with this fan?

Comment: Would check all wire connections for tightness, at fan and switch.  Vibration and/or heat might be cause a bad connection/low voltage, fan slows down and cools and speed comes back up.

Comment: does the fan feels hot to the touch

Comment: The fan housing feels a bit hot, but not excessively so. I’m disassembling the fan now to check wire connections, but so far everything seems ok…

Comment: Check the brushes for the brush motor, take them out and rotate 180 Dgr

Comment: Ok. I’m not entirely sure how to open the motor. It’s the MT-515, pictured here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/250291/does-this-hampton-bay-ceiling-fan-have-a-capacitor-inside-the-motor-housing. There are four screws on the top and four on the bottom - I’ve popped out all of them but the housing doesn’t budge :(

Comment: FWIW instructions for Model D5201: https://secure.img1.wfrcdn.com/docresources/0/36/366699.pdf  Seems to be "Harbor Breeze" branded fan.

Comment: Ugh. I re-tightened all the electrical connections I could find, then on a lark I decided to run the motor without the blades attached. Motor didn't get hot at all, but still slowed down to a crawl at around 20 minutes. So it's probably not overheating...